# HornetQ support in JBoss7 eap

Tags: jboss7.x, activemq-artemis, hornetq

In Jboss7 EAP ActiveMQ Artemis is the default messaging system. Is the older HornetQ still supported? If I want my war to use HornetQ instead of ActiveMQ Artemis will it be possible?

Comment: Do you have a driving reason to use HornetQ? Artemis is the next-gen HornetQ and the ActiveMQ is considering a merge of the two.

Answer (score 3):

Jboss EAP 7 use the Apache Artemis message broker. HornetQ is not supported with EAP 7.
From my experience, it is tested with HornetQ clients, version 2.3 or later.
As far as I know, Red Hat will support the use of Artemis in EAP 7 with HornetQ client runtime from EAP 6.

However, I do not think that this product combination will be supported in the next EAP version(release 8 or later).

What I propose is to migrate your existing HornetQ configuration on JBoss EAP 6 to ArtemisMQ on JBoss EAP 7.
For your info, JBoss EAP 7 is shipped with migration tools, built to help move configuration from EAP 6 to EAP 7. For more info, please have a look on the official [migration documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en/red-hat-jboss-enterprise-application-platform/version-7.0/migration-guide/#migrate_messaging_server_configuration_changes).